# How to have multiple int values in every element in a one dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, int

i want to fill one  one dimensional array with two int values.

When i run my code without brackets around the values i get only the frist int and when i run it with brackets around the values i get only the second int.

Output should be like x/y

thank you for your time.

```
int main()
{
    cBruch cBruch[7];

    cBruch[0] = (3, 4);
    cBruch[1] = (24, -6);
    cBruch[2] = -5, -3;
    cBruch[3] = -14, 22;
    cBruch[4] = 21, 45;
    cBruch[5] = 7, -9;
    cBruch[6] = 2, 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cBruch[i].ausgabe();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

.h

```
class cBruch
{
private:
    int zaehler;
    int nenner;

    int ggt(int a, int b);
    void kuerzen();

public:
    cBruch(int zaehler_in = 0, int nenner_in = 1);
    ~cBruch();

    void ausgabe(); //output
};
```

.cpp

```
cBruch::cBruch(int zaehler_in, int nenner_in)
{
    zaehler = zaehler_in;
    nenner = nenner_in;

    cout << "Konstruktor Zaehler = " << zaehler << " Nenner = " << nenner << endl;
}

cBruch::~cBruch()
{
    cout << "Destruktor Zaehler = " << zaehler << " Nenner = " << nenner << endl;
}

void cBruch::ausgabe()
{
    cout << "Bruch: " << zaehler << "/" << nenner << "\tGleitkommazahl: "<< double(zaehler) / nenner << endl;
}
```

Comment: use a std::pair

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i thougt this were enough. I updated my code

Comment: Apparently I can't read... You need `{}` rather than `()`.

Comment: See [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) and also [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat omg thank you i didnt realize this too.

Comment: Do not update your title or question body with any text claiming it is "solved". Instead, you should accept the best answer (this is how questions are marked as having a solution). If no existing answer answers your question, you can create and accept your own answer.

Comment: @crashmstr done. I can accept my own answer in two days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should initialize your array like following:

```
cBruch cBruch[] = {{3, 4},{24, -6},{-5, -3},{-14, 22},{21, 45},{7, -9},{2, 3}};
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to use a different name for the variable than for the type

Answer (score 1):

The [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) will always evaluate both sides and return the right hand side. It also has the [lowest precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of all opearators.

So, this:

```
cBruch[2] = -5, -3;
```

evaluates to:

```
(cBruch[2] = -5), -3;
```

And this:

```
cBruch[0] = (3, 4);
```

Will evaluate to:

```
cBruch[0] = 4;
```

You probably should use an array (or better yet a [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) of for example [`std::pair<int, int>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).